# Delayed Job not picking job from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

In my current project I am doing some process in background by using Delayed Job gem. It's working fine in local but in production jobs are inserted into Delayed Job table but DJ not picking few jobs from that DJ table. Could any one have idea how Delayed Job will pick up jobs from Delayed Job table.

**Below is the Delayed job code in my project:**

`Delayed::Job.enqueue(ProposalJob.new(current_user, @proposal, request.host, params[:proposal][:revision_notes], params[:proposal][:close_date]), :queue => 'publishing')`

**Delayed job configuration in my project:**

`Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
  Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 3
  Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 1.hours
  Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 10`

Comment: Have you started the delayed job process in production?

Comment: Yes... Its working fine in production. Jobs are inserted into Delayed job table, but DJ not processed few jobs and deleted from the database with out any error in log.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible that delayed job will pick some job and not pick other. 
Either it will process all job or not process any. If it process any job then your configuration is right.

There might be issue due to `Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false` this configuration. if your any job fails three times then it will not get deleted from your delayed job table. Because of due to this you might feel that this jobs not get processed.

Try debug your delayed job code with `puts`.

You can also try https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler this will provide visual way to watch delayed jobs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The same issue was there before I added Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false. But when it will reach max attempts it will remove from failed jobs from the DB. We want to see failed job info So I have added above configuration. In controller I have added logger there I am able to see record inserted into DJ table. But it's not processed and removed from DB and also I am unable to see any error in delayed job log.

Comment: Try use resque-scheduler it will give you all info regarding failed jobs and also error logs. You can also reprocess your jobs using it

Comment: Can we use resque-scheduler for delayed job enqueue? I saw the doc but I am not getting idea. Can you please check this question I have posted my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033860/few-jobs-are-not-coming-to-delayedjob-queue

Comment: You can have a look at here http://blog.togo.io/how-to/resque-scheduler/ and http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque?view=asciicast this will help you solve problem

Comment: I checked both. It seems resque-scheduler is alternative for delayed-job gem. Am I right?