# how to update DELAYED_JOB_ACTIVE_RECORD gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

In my current project I am using delayed_job(4.0.4) and delayed_job_active_record(4.0.0) gems. Now I want to update delayed_job_active_record gem to latest version.

I checked official doc but we can upgrade delayed job by using following command but not delayed_job_active_record

rails g delayed_job:upgrade.

Please let me know how I need to upgrade delayed_job_active_record gem.

Answer (score 0):

In you Gemfile add

```
gem '#GEM_NAME', '#GEM_VERSION'
```

eg.

if earlier it was

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '4.0.0'
```

change it to

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '4.0.4'
```

After that run:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Could you please check this post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772330/delayed-job-not-picking-job-from-table) once and let me know some suggestions  ?

I am facing this issue since 2 months.

Comment: if you read the github instructions you'll find `rails generate delayed_job:upgrade` is required to upgrade from 2.x to 3x this is because they made changes to database table which needs new migration. while upgrading to subversion of same group migration is not needed. One thing you can do is remove the `Gemfile.lock` and try again. I'll suggest get a backup of file before removing

Comment: Yes... I did the same as you specified in your comment. But here the problem is Job is Inserted into DelayedJob table and DJ is not executing that job and removed that job from DB.

Comment: yeah you cannot do that while your jobs are running. You have to stop the delayed job worked  for that. In your dev environment, you may try msqldump to rescue jobs from getting lost, before upgrading

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. Actually What I mentioned in my last comment is the original problem so that's the reason I am updating all delayed_job version that may be resolve that issue.